# NiFi - TailFile - multiple files

Tags: file, directory, apache-nifi, tail

In the following path, i have the following logs:

When 10MB are reached for metricbeat file, it will go to write on metricbeat.1 and when this file size exceeds also, it will write to metricbeat.2 etc

```
[root@ metricbeat]# ls -lorth
total 4.1M
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nifi   10 Aug 17 11:17 metricbeat.2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nifi   10 Aug 17 11:17 metricbeat.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nifi 4.1M Aug 17 11:47 metricbeat
```

In NiFi (no cluster) I want to tail all the files that are stored on path

```
/logs/metricbeat/
```

I am using TailFile Processor with the following Configuration:

[image: TailFile NiFi Processor Configuration]

But, the main problem is that i am getting the following error:

```
'File to Tail' is invalid because There is no file to tail. Files must exist when starting this processor.
```

If i select the "Single Line" it gets the file "metricbeat"

Could you please tell me what i am doing wrong? Or how can i read all the "metricbeat" files from that path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Single File" mode does not require the file to exist before starting the processor, while "Multiple Files" mode does - hence the error you see.